# Assign product category to specific store

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, category-products

I've been trying for a while now to assign a product to a new category. We are running multiple store views, but when i try to assign the products to the new category IDs the original product is also affected.

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($this->_targetStoreId)->load($productId);
$newProduct->setCategoryIds($newCategoryIds);
$newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
```

Can anyone see the bug?

For some products i get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '47893-0-6-8' for key 'FA0D1FDA369EC09AFFDA36F11B04E66B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The product - category relation s global.
- It does not depend on the store view or website.
- What you can do is to have a different category tree on the second 
  website.
- But this will result in duplicate categories.

When you see `catalog_category_product` table, and it only has `category_id` and `product_id` not `store_id`

Comment: you are always welcome @fatkid